# Javascript file linking problem when integrating template

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am having some trouble getting started with using javascript files on my website. The website(in master.blade.php) already had some javascript files linked up when I integrated the template to my Laravel project. But now, I wanted to add a new javascript file to the master.blade.php file called app.js vue file. After adding this vue file the Design part has been broke down. Now, How can I solve that issue.

Here is the master.blade.php file's javascript file linked up portion.

This is the old one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=" 
{{asset('local_agent\files\bower_components\jquery\js\jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('local_agent\files\bower_components\jquery-ui\js\jquery-ui.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=" 
 {{asset('local_agent\files\bower_components\popper.js\js\popper.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=" 
 {{asset('local_agent\files\bower_components\bootstrap\js\bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('local_agent\files\bower_components\jquery- slimscroll\js\jquery.slimscroll.js')}}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=" 
 {{asset('local_agent\files\bower_components\modernizr\js\modernizr.js')}}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=" 
 {{asset('local_agent\files\bower_components\chart.js\js\Chart.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('local_agent\files\assets\pages\widget\amchart\amcharts.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('local_agent\files\assets\pages\widget\amchart\serial.js')}}"></script>
 <script src="{{asset('local_agent\files\assets\pages\widget\amchart\light.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('local_agent\files\assets\js\jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js')}}"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('local_agent\files\assets\js\SmoothScroll.js')}}"> 
</script>
<script src="{{asset('local_agent\files\assets\js\pcoded.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('local_agent\files\assets\js\vartical-layout.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('local_agent\files\assets\pages\dashboard\custom- dashboard.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('local_agent\files\assets\js\script.min.js')}}"></script>
<script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-23581568-13"></script>
 <script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-23581568-13');
</script>
```

This is the new one:

```
  <script src="{{asset('/js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

After adding this script the problem has been occurred

Comment: what problem has occurred?

Comment: Style broke down

Comment: perhaps you can elaborate as you not giving any detail to go off of .. is there a javascript error some where?

Comment: Ok, I am letting you know.

Comment: I solved all of the javascript error. But now The display appears just loading. Nothing shows. Even DOM elements are disappeared now.